# Проблема со словарем при проверке орфографии

Tags: c#, wpf, проверка-орфографии

Столкнулся с проблемой при проверке орфографии:
Я сделал словарь (http://yadi.sk/d/YIPIfIfEBBTuj), как сказано [тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.customdictionaries.aspx)

Я его добавил к `TextBox`:

```
<SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries>
                  <System:Uri>pack://application:,,,/Dictionaries/Russian.lex</System:Uri>
</SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries>
```

Но он работает не так (откуда-то взялись символы Enter => проверка орфографии не работает):

[image]

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Проверьте, в том ли формате словарь. Может, ему нужны не такие концы строк?

Comment: Ну, вроде бы те концы строк, что и надо.

Comment: А вы перепроверьте, а то откуда взялся возврат строки после предлагаемого варианта на вашем скриншоте?

Comment: Я раз 5 проверил - ошибок не нашел

Comment: А какие концы строк в словаре? Просто интересно. Если `\r\n`, почему бы не попробовать поменять на просто `\n`?

Comment: Тогда к концу слова добавляются 'левые' буквы

Comment: Мне так же нужно сделать проверку орфографии, дайте пример пожалуйста 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сам решил проблему. Словарь был сохранен в кодировке UTF8, а должен был - в Unicode.

Comment: если это возможно, было бы здорово посмотреть ваш исходный код